# grep string from a TCL variable

Tags: unix, grep, tcl

I want to grep a certain amount of string from a TCL variable and use that in my tool command. Example:

> ${tcl_Var} - this contains string like VEG_0_1/ABC

I want to grep from above string until it the point it hits first forward slash, so in the above case it would be VEG_0_1. And then replace it in my command. Example:

> VEG_0_1/REST_OF_THE_COMMAND.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think in terms of `grep`, think about "string manipulation" instead.

Use `regsub` for "search and replace:

```
% set tcl_Var VEG_0_1/ABC
VEG_0_1/ABC
% set newvar [regsub {/.+} $tcl_Var {/REST_OF_THE_COMMAND}]
VEG_0_1/REST_OF_THE_COMMAND
```

Alternately, your problem can be solved by splitting the string on <kbd>/</kbd>, taking the first component, then appending the "rest of the command":

```
% set newvar "[lindex [split $tcl_Var /] 0]/REST_OF_THE_COMMAND"
VEG_0_1/REST_OF_THE_COMMAND
```

Or using string indices:

```
% set newvar "[string range $tcl_Var 0 [string first / $tcl_Var]]REST_OF_THE_COMMAND"
VEG_0_1/REST_OF_THE_COMMAND
```

Comment: You Sir ! A life Saver. The solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regular expressions using the `regsub` TCL command. There is no need to run the external program `grep`. See more info here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regsub.htm

If you are new to regular expressions, read TCL-specific tutorial about them.

Answer (score -1):

```
set tcl_Var VEG_0_1/ABC  
set varlist [split $tcl_Var "/"]  
set newvar [lindex $varlist 0]/REST_OF_THE_COMMAND
```